# Tabs in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, user-controls, tabs

I have three tabs on page and one user control.
I want to RenderPartial on each tab.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#tabs").tabs();               
    });    
</script>


<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Text 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Text 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Text 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <% Html.RenderPartial("usercontrol", Model);  %>            
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <% Html.RenderPartial("usercontrol", Model);  %>            
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <% Html.RenderPartial("usercontrol", Model);  %>            
    </div>
</div>
```

how can i get values from different tabs.

Comment: What type of values do you want from each tab?

Comment: I have complete in usercontrol when i submit the form complete form's values will be saved in DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to recognize tab, which sent data back, you'll have to pass additional parameter to every partial view:

```
public class UserControlModel
{
    ModelType ParentModel { get; set; }
    string ID { get; set; }
}

<div id="tabs-1">
    <% Html.RenderPartial("usercontrol", new UserControlModel { ParentModel = Model, ID = "tab1" });  %>            
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
    <% Html.RenderPartial("usercontrol", new UserControlModel { ParentModel = Model, ID = "tab2" });  %>            
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
    <% Html.RenderPartial("usercontrol", new UserControlModel { ParentModel = Model, ID = "tab3" });  %>            
</div>
```

Then use Html.Hidden to store value in form in partial view and by checking value in post method, you can recognize tab.

Your partial view will have to inherit from `ViewUserControl<TaskEditModel>`:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<TaskEditModel>" %>
```